# weird execution plan of a SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan

Context: SQL Server 2008. There are 2 tables to inner join.
The fact table, which has 40 million rows, contains the patient key and the medications administered and other facts. There is a unique index (nonclustered) on medication key and patient key combined in that order.
The dimension table is the medication list (70 rows).
The join is to get the medication code (business code) based on medication key (surrogate key).
Query:

```
SELECT a.PKey, a.SomeFact, b.MCode
FROM tblFact a
JOIN tblDIM b ON a.MKey = b.MKey
```

All the columns returned are integer.
The above query runs in 7 minutes and its execution plan shows the index on (MKey,PKey) is used. The index was rebuilt right before the run.
When I disabled the index on the fact table (or copy data to a new table with same structure but without index), the same query takes only 1:40 minutes.

IO Statistics are also stunning.

With index: Table 'tblFACT'. Scan count 70, logical reads 190296338, physical reads 685138, read-ahead reads 98713

Without index: Table 'tblFACT_copy'. Scan count 17, logical reads 468891, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 419768

Question: why does it try to use the index and head down the inefficient path?

Comment: Can we see the index definitions and the execution plan? Does it have to do an RID_LOOKUP with your index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rare cases, the database chooses an incorrect execution plan. In this case, the index is used for the join, but since all data is fetched from both tables, it would be faster to just scan the whole table.
The indexed version will be much faster if you add a WHERE clause to the query, because without indexes it will still need to scan the whole table, instead of grabbing just the handful of records it needs.

There may be directives to encourage the database not to use indexes or use different indexes, but I don't know SQL server that well.

Comment: Just FYI, `FROM YourTable WITH (INDEX(0))` forces a table scan

Comment: And in SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 and Denali, you can use `FORCESCAN` to force a scan of any index - though there are doubtful to be too many non-academic cases where this will be useful. It can also be humorous to say that word out loud in a crowded presentation hall, depending on your accent. :-)  See https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/04/22/sql-server-2008-r2-sp1-ctp-is-now-available.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373%28SQL.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `SomeFact` as an INCLUDE on the `tblFact` index to make it [covering](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/).

Currently, the table will be accessed twice: once for the index and then again for a lookup to get `SomeFact` either as a RID or key lookup (depends on if there is a clustered index)

This doesn't apply to `tblDIM` because I assume that `MKey` is the clustered index which makes it covering implicitly

Comment: +1 - I'm sure he's still having to pull all the pages for the clustered index

Comment: well with the current execution plan, the index is accessed 70 times (equal the number of rows in the dim table). There's the key lookup (clustered index). I'm hesitant to make the index fully covering, since fact columns vary by the queries.

Comment: @vuht2000: Three options: 1. No index, every query will take 1:40 2. Make (Mkey, Pkey) the clustered index 3. Make the current index covering. Your choice...

Comment: @gbn: thanks. I moved Mkey to be second column in the index and it works as expected. However I still can't avoid wondering why SQL Server makes such a bad choice with a rather simple query. Agreed if the query were to have a filter, say on a particular patient, then the use of index makes sense. But SQL Server clearly knows the expected numbers of rows with or without a filter.

Comment: @vuht2000: With MKey 2nd I suspect it isn't using the index because it's useless: it's the same as no index (compare plans) but just takes up disk space

Comment: I understand. But the index is still useful for queries that filter on both PKey and MKey, I guess? Just a way to disable index for this type of query. Do you have an insight why the index was used inappropriately? Is it a consistent behavior of SQL Server or just a rarity?

Comment: The index was used "inappropriately" probabaly because of poor statisitic: did you do a fullscan so SQL Server knew the exact distribution of rows? If not (you let it do the default sampling), SQL Server estimates won't be correct so it doesn't know to ignore the index. GolezTrol's answer is correct but they don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Are your statistics up to date?  Check with:

```
SELECT object_name = Object_Name(ind.object_id)
,      IndexName = ind.name
,      StatisticsDate = STATS_DATE(ind.object_id, ind.index_id)
FROM   SYS.INDEXES ind
order by
       STATS_DATE(ind.object_id, ind.index_id) desc
```

Update with:

```
exec sp_updatestats;
```

Comment: OP said "The index was rebuilt right before the run": index statistics are always updated by index rebuilds (but not column indexes). Basically, tblFact index isn't covering